# device eth1 does not seem to be present

Tags: wifi, udev

fedora-3 (I know, it is ancient, but this is my sandbox where I look under the hood), udev-039, kernel 2.6.27, configured and compiled by myself. 
I'm using pci wifi card with ath9k module. 
Kudzu recognizes hardware, assigns eth1 interface, but device is missing. 
dmesg shows ath9k: 0,1 - looks like no warning. 
/sys directory does show details on bus. Tried adding udev rules file with reference to vendor and product id but still cannot activate device. Any ideas on what is going on or how to fix it?

F.Y.I. booting same box into ubuntu 14.04 card and wifi is working.

Comment: What is the output of `ip link show`?

Comment: Why not replace the ancient distro on your sandbox with one that has been maintained the past 10 years? I really don't see any sensible reason to invest time into such a problem.

Comment: @ZacharyBrady very similar to output of ifconfig, showing only interfaces lo and eth0 'code'1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,10000> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,10000> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:18:ed:a7:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: Look into using backports but that may not work if you don't have kernel headers or the necessary packages to built kernel modules

Comment: @jeremy31 - I do not understand "backport" or "building kernel modules". I have compiled kernel 2.6.27 and configured it to build ath9k as a module. I'm running the fc3 boot with 2.6.27 kernel. It does load ath9k module and /sys does recognize the bus and the card. If I knew more about linux and c I would suspect that udev is unable to create device corresponding to the wifi card that has the ath9k driver.

Comment: What is the result for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: @jeremy31 - I could not run lspci with -nnk option, but here is the output with -m option. I also added relevant section of the lsmod output. Item 00:04.0 is the wired, working ethernet card, device eth1 with forcedeth module, and item 01:07.0 is the new wifi card with ath9k module. Thanks for your interest in helping with this issue.

Comment: @jeremy31 - ` /sbin/lspci -m | grep -iA2 net
00:04.0 "Ethernet controller" "NVIDIA Corporation" "nForce Ethernet Controller" -rc2 "ASUSTeK Computer Inc." "0c11"
01:07.0 "Network controller" "Qualcomm Atheros" "AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter" -r01 "Qualcomm Atheros" "0300"
`

Comment: Sorry, I tried to use the `code` formatting and apparently it did not work

Comment: here is the lsmod: code ath9k                 265044  0 
mac80211              158204  1 ath9k
cfg80211               22952  1 mac80211
forcedeth              50868  0

Comment: See if you can use kernel 2.6.32 as wikidevi.com says that kernel supports the AR9227

Comment: @jeremy31 - yes, I thought ath9k covers all. So the version in 2.6.32 kernel would probably work. Alas, I ran into compiling error: kernel/built-in.o(.text+0x5c9c): In function `update_sysctl':
: undefined reference to `____ilog2_NaN'
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1

Comment: You could try manually patching your 2.6.27 source code with https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/92946/ and then just compile the ath9k module

Comment: @jeremy31 - thank you so much! I compiled gcc-4.2.1 to replace the fc3 installation of gcc-3.4.4.2. Now kernel-2.6.32.71 compiled flawlessly and finally wlan0 is there, my wifi card works! case closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was that initial release of ath9k driver in kernel-2.6.27 had limited chipset support. Kernel-2.6.32 has support for the AR9227 chip in TP-LINK TL-WN851ND PCI card. Credit for the solution goes to @jeremy31 who suspected that the installed ath9k driver may not support the actual chipset. What I have learned is that even if module installs without error and even if dmesg signals no error things may still not work as intended. - Yes, old machine, old linux, but good education. Thanks again, Zachary Brady and Jeremy31